# NumberFormatException: For input String

Tags: java, excepciones, jtable, numberformat

Necesito actualizar registros en mi base de datos sql desde un jtable, para esto implemento el siguiente método:

```
public void actualizarDatos(JTable table) {
        int fila = table.getSelectedRow();
        int columna = table.getSelectedColumn();
        
        int id = Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(fila, columna).toString());
        String titulo = table.getValueAt(fila, columna).toString();
        String descripcion = table.getValueAt(fila, columna).toString();
        String fecha_reclamo = table.getValueAt(fila, columna).toString();
        String hora = table.getValueAt(fila, columna).toString();
        String nombre_evento = table.getValueAt(fila, columna).toString();
        String nombre_actividad = table.getValueAt(fila, columna).toString();
        int semestre = Integer.parseInt(this.table.getValueAt(fila, columna).toString());
        String fecha_actividad = table.getValueAt(fila, columna).toString();
        String docente = table.getValueAt(fila, columna).toString();
        int creditos  = Integer.parseInt(this.table.getValueAt(fila, columna).toString());
        String usuario = table.getValueAt(fila, columna).toString();
        String estado = table.getValueAt(fila, columna).toString();
        
        
        try {
            PreparedStatement actu = DatabaseManager.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE RECLAMO SET TITULO='"+titulo+"', DESCRIPCION='"+descripcion+"', FECHA_RECLAMO='"+fecha_reclamo+"', HORA='"+hora+"', "
                    + "NOMBRE_EVENTO='"+nombre_evento+"', NOMBRE_ACTIVIDAD='"+nombre_actividad+"', SEMESTRE='"+semestre+"', FECHA_ACTIVIDAD='"+fecha_actividad+"', DOCENTE='"+docente+"', CREDITOS='"+creditos+"', USUARIO='"+usuario+"', ESTADO='"+estado+"' "
                            + "WHERE ID_RECLAMO='"+id+"'");
            actu.executeUpdate();

        
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo actualizar");
        }
        
    }
```

Coloque lo que coloque en el registro que quiera actualizar (asi como si tambien no cambio nada y ejecuto el metodo) me da el error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException. Podrían decirme cómo solucionarlo, o en su defecto recomendarme algun tutorial o cómo lograr actualizar registros en mi tabla en BD desde Jtable. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Es evidente que obtienes el error `NumberFormatException` luego de intentar convertir un `String` en un `int`.

Yo me pregunto, ¿para qué convertir el valor de la celda en un `String`?

La función [`getValueAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt(int,%20int)) devuelve un `Object`. En teoría puedes simplemente hacer un typecast para obtener el tipo original.

Si en la celda ingresaste un `int`, debería ser tan fácil como escribir:

```
int valor = (int)table.getValueAt(...);
```

Así mismo, si ingresaste un `long` o un `String` deberías poder escribir:

```
long cadena = (long)table.getValueAt(...);
String cadena = (String)table.getValueAt(...);
```

---

Si desconoces el tipo al que deberías convertir la variable, siempre puedes verla desde el debugger u obtenerla mediante la función [`getClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) que todos los objetos tienen:

```
objeto.getClass();
```

[Aquí](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJ/v@/oDQpJzNZITknsbhYwTcxM0@hmksBCKDixSWJJUCqLD8zRSEXKKsRXFKUmZceHauQWJRerAlUzOmflJWaXKKQn5SlYKtgag3WDQLBlcUlqbl6@aUlegVAPSU5eRpANZqEFOilp5Y4g1yjoQlVW8tV@/8/AA) puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando.

Así que siempre que veas un `Object`, siéntete invitado a convertirlo de nuevo a su tipo original.

Comment: al castear mis variables definidas como int ahora obtengo el error  java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer, no entiendo por que lo obtengo porque en mi BD a los valores que refiero en estas variables son de tipo INTEGER, y en mi JTable aparecen correctamente. No se si tienes idea de como podria solucionar esto, de todas formas muchas gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: @Santiago ¿Les quitaste los `toString()` que estás usando en tu código?

Comment: Si, deje los strings de la forma String cadena = (String)table.getValueAt(...); y los int de la forma int valor = (int)table.getValueAt(...);

Comment: ¿Entonces en la tabla ingresas los números como cadenas de caracteres? Bueno, en ese caso si necesitas hacer una conversión, con `Integer.parseInt` o `Integer.valueOf`. Deberías ver qué la cadena contenga un número válido.